# How to import another class in Python?

Tags: python, windows, class, oop, import

How to import another class into python?
I just started learning python and I don't understand importing. there are two files in one folder. How to import?

Answer (score 0):

Its really easy.

If you want to import a class from another file just write at the start of the file.

from *name of the file* import *name of the class*

Remember to put the two files in the folder. :3

Comment: just the file name or extension? I have 2 file. First.py, and Second.py 2 file in 1 folder. i would like to import second.py in first.py... i can use import Sedond.py in the First.py file, but doesn't work... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can just import the file using the below command at the beginning of your python file. Keep both the file in the same folder.

```
import file_name
```